# I have always seen this inversion in past tense. Is this correct for simple present?

Tags: grammar, inversion

Is the following sentence correct? I used inversion, and instead of telling "people are able to", I wrote "are people able to"

> Only after a well-planned diet are people able to lose weight.

I wonder if it is correct to say so, regardless of verb tense?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly correct.

Comment: Only after reading your question did I realise there was inversion in that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

> Only after a well-planned diet are people able to lose weight.